# Angular Global Sass Variables for @media

Tags: angular, sass

I am trying to create a global sass variable that allows me to define the size of a phone/tablet. However, I am failing to import it into my sass stylesheets.

angular.json

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I have this in `build`, `test`, and `deploy` options.

Then in `styles.sass`, located in the `src` folder:

```
$layout-small: 500px
```

And finally, in my stylesheet `home.component.sass`:

```
@import styles

@media (max-width: $layout-small)
   ...
```

I get the error that `Can't find stylesheet to import.`

I have attempted to include the variable in `:root` of `styles.sass`, but it doesn't seem to be recognized by the `@media` call then.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration in `angular.json` to include `src` in `stylePreprocessorOptions` seems correct. However, there are a couple of things to check or adjust:

1. **File Extension**:

   - Since you're using the `.sass` syntax (indented), make sure your files indeed have the `.sass` extension (not `.scss`).
2. **Import Path**:

   - If you have specified `"includePaths": ["src"]` in `angular.json`, then the `@import` directive will look for files starting from the `src` directory.
   - Given that `styles.sass` is directly under `src`, you should import it like:

     ```
     @import 'styles'
     ```
3. **File Names with Underscores**:

   - If the above methods don't solve the problem, try renaming `styles.sass` to `_styles.sass`. In Sass, files that start with an underscore are considered "partials". They don't get compiled into CSS files on their own. Instead, they're meant to be imported into other Sass files. So the underscore signifies that it's a file to be imported, not compiled.
4. **Clear Cache**:

   - Sometimes, the Angular CLI might not pick up changes immediately, especially if there have been modifications to `angular.json`. Make sure to stop the `ng serve` process, clear any cache if necessary, and then restart it.
5. **Variable Availability**:

   - If you define a variable in `:root`, that makes it a CSS custom property (or variable), which is different from a Sass variable. CSS custom properties are accessible in pure CSS and can be used with the `var()` function. Sass variables, on the other hand, are available only during preprocessing and don't exist in the output CSS. So, stick with defining `$layout-small` as you did without `:root`.

Try the steps above and see if it resolves the issue. If the problem persists, double-check the path configurations and file locations to ensure there aren't any typos or misconfigurations.

Comment: 3 fixed it! Thank you for your help.